Informatica cloud data quality rule validation issue
I have been trying to create a data quality rule in Informatica cloud DQ service. The rule is to check the input is 'Integer' value or not (Validity dimension). The rule logic which I mentioned was : If Input is IS_Number() then valid otherwise Invalid. Note: I changed the Input field type to string as well, but no luck.
I have received the below error message.
'An input data type does not match the data type that a condition specifies.' Please see attached screen shot.
Thanks in advance
I tried If Input is IS_Number() then valid otherwise Invalid.Please find attached screenshot
Answer:
Here is the right answer

On the screenshot provided you compare the no_of_employees (integer value) to boolean (true/false). Hence the comparison doesn't work. You literally have a rule:
no_of_employees is IS_NUMBER(no_of_employees)

for example, this will evaluate to
8 = True

Try the below instead:
True is IS_NUMBER(no_of_employees)

Such condition will check if it is True that no_of_employees is numeric.

Thank you so much, Your explanation is great...
